# Open popup window when scan a barcode

Tags: php, barcode, barcode-scanner

I'm trying to call a js function which will open a small page when i scan the barcode. Can it be achieved?

This is my code:

```
<script>
function PopupCenter(url, title, w, h) {  

var dualScreenLeft = window.screenLeft != undefined ? window.screenLeft  :screen.left;  
var dualScreenTop = window.screenTop != undefined ? window.screenTop : screen.top;  

width = window.innerWidth ? window.innerWidth : document.documentElement.clientWidth ? document.documentElement.clientWidth : screen.width;  
height = window.innerHeight ? window.innerHeight : document.documentElement.clientHeight ? document.documentElement.clientHeight : screen.height;  

var left = ((width / 2) - (w / 2)) + dualScreenLeft;  
var top = ((height / 2) - (h / 2)) + dualScreenTop;  
var newWindow = window.open(url, title, 'scrollbars=yes, width=' + w + ', height=' + h + ', top=' + top + ', left=' + left);  

//  Puts focus on the newWindow  
if (window.focus) {  
   newWindow.focus(); 
   newWindow.document.bgColor="grey"; 
   //window.opener.document.body.style.backgroundColor = "grey"; 
}  
}
</script>

<form method="post" action="action.php">
<input type="button" class="searchbutton" value="" onclick="PopupCenter('barcode.php','BARCODE',1000,500)"/>
</form>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: It depends, does the barcode reader interact with JavaScript? If so you'll need to identify the `ontrigger` listener. For example, with jQuery when a button is clicked on it triggers the `click` listener.

Comment: @Styphon, i haven't test the barcode scanner yet. but i just want the code to be ready. Just assume the scanner can interact with javascript, do you have any simple example of the code to trigger the function?

Comment: No, there's no way we can know what code will work as we don't know how your barcode scanner interacts with JavaScript. You'll need to contact the manufacturer / supplier for instructions on how to integrate it.